# SMT: check uniqueness and totality of function

Tags: z3, smt

Given is a function and a description of its behavior:

```
add: (ℤ ∪ {Error, None})² → (ℤ ∪ {Error, None})

For x ∈ (ℤ ∪ {Error, None}):
add(x, None) = add(None, x) = None

For x ∈ (ℤ ∪ {Error}):
add(x, Error) = add(Error, x) = Error

For x, y ∈ ℤ:
add(x, y) = x + y
```

How can I transform this description to SMT (I'm using Z3) and check whether the description defines a total function?

To give you an idea what I want to achieve: in the end I want to generate Python code implementing this function with the minimum number of branches.  For example:

```
def add(x, y):
    if x is None or y is None:
        return None
    if x is Error or y is Error:
        return Error
    return x + y
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((ABC (int (val Int)) error none)))
(declare-fun f (ABC ABC) ABC)
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error) (= x none)) (= (f none x) none))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error) (= x none)) (= (f x none) none))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error)) (= (f error x) error))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error)) (= (f x error) error))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC) (y ABC)) (=> (and (is-int x) (is-int y)) (= (f x y) (int (+ (val x) (val y)))))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This timeouts.

EDIT: In [Simplify function interpretation in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501984/simplify-function-interpretation-in-model) I described a simpler axiomatization of f where `int` is a single case, resulting in finitely many cases.  Can I somehow tell Z3 that the concrete `val` in `int` doesn't matter and there are effectively finitely many cases?

Answer (score 1):

To check uniqueness: Your axiomatization is good; you just need to "replicate" it for two functions then ask for two values such that they differ:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((ABC (int (val Int)) error none)))

(declare-fun f (ABC ABC) ABC)
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error) (= x none)) (= (f none x) none))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error) (= x none)) (= (f x none) none))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error)) (= (f error x) error))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error)) (= (f x error) error))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC) (y ABC)) (=> (and (is-int x) (is-int y)) (= (f x y) (int (+ (val x) (val y)))))))

(declare-fun g (ABC ABC) ABC)
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error) (= x none)) (= (g none x) none))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error) (= x none)) (= (g x none) none))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error)) (= (g error x) error))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC)) (=> (or (is-int x) (= x error)) (= (g x error) error))))
(assert (forall ((x ABC) (y ABC)) (=> (and (is-int x) (is-int y)) (= (g x y) (int (+ (val x) (val y)))))))

; check that there is no {x,y} such that f and g differ on:
(declare-const x ABC)
(declare-const y ABC)
(assert (not (= (f x y) (g x y))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Z3 quickly returns unsat for this; meaning `f` and `g` cannot differ. Now, you can try commenting out some of the asserts for `f` and/or `g` and ask for a model. Depending on which asserts you comment out, Z3 might come up with a model for `f` and `g` such that they have different behavior; *OR* it can still time-out, trying to construct a model to do so. In the presence of quantifiers, you can't really expect anything better from an SMT solver.

Comment: If the function specification is contradicting, Z3 will always return unsat (unless it timeouts or fails). Can I somehow guard against this?

Comment: @ManuelJacob You can `(check-sat)` both before and after the last assertion -- it should be sat before, unsat after.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple Sure, but the point of the question was that checking satisfiability before the last assertion times out.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do. Once quantifiers are involved, all the solver can do is to throw heuristics at it, which may or may not work.

Comment: @LeventErkok you wrote "To check uniqueness". But doesn't it actually check for totality? Suppose that f (and therefore g) isn't total, i.e. f is undefined for some x. Z3 would be able to construct a model where f and g have a different image for x.

Comment: No, it is checking for uniqueness. That is, if `f` and `g` satisfies those axioms, then `f` and `g` must agree on all inputs; i.e., they must be equivalent. Hence, there's only one function that satisfies those axioms.

You can't really check for "totality" in SMT-Lib; as all functions are by definition total. It's a logic of total-functions. So, it's a moot question. Perhaps what you mean is "if none of the inputs is `error` then neither is the output." You can formulate and check for that, but keep in mind that notion of totality is something you impose yourself, outside the logic.

Comment: I think there is a terminology issue. When you say "uniqueness", you mean that at most one function exists. When I think of "uniqueness", I think of the right-uniqueness of a function, i.e. that each pre-image has at most one image. Specifically, I was referring to the right-uniqueness of the function *description*. Regarding "totality": sure, every function in SMT-LIB is total. When I said "totality", I meant that the function *description* assigns some image for each pre-image. If this isn't the case, Z3 can provide two different models. Confusingly, this is what you mean by "not unique".

Comment: My use of the terms total/unique is consistent with the usage of the term as referred to in computer-science/theorem proving communities. All SMT-Lib function declarations are total (ipso facto), while they may or may not correspond to a unique function in the logic. This goes for all uninterpreted function symbols in SMTLib, and also in HOL and similar logics that's commonly used in theorem proving. Of course, it's moot to argue about definitions: They are what you define them to be; and I'm only familiar with the theorem-proving/computer-science world-view.